# undefined method `client_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, haml, form-for

I have a partial (haml) in my Rails program. In the partial, I'm trying to put a form_for block. however, it's giving me `undefined method`client_path'`

The form looks like:

```
    = simple_form_for current_client, remote: true do |f|
      = f.label 'checkbox'
      = f.check_box :show_help_slide_show, autofocus: true
      = f.submit
```

current_client exists, and is a client object, I've checked.

I've used both current_client, @current_client, client, and @client. none work. (client doesn't seem to be defined).

As you can see from what I've tried, I'm a fairly novice Ruby programmer (but very experienced otherwise) I don't understand how data gets passed around within a ruby program I guess...

Comment: for this problem, I think you need upload the content of your config/routes.rb and your controller for this view

Comment: if it's in partial maybe try to define the local variable. In main view: `= render partial: 'my_partial', locals: { current_client: current_client }`

Answer (score 0):

You pass an object `current_client` to **simple_form**.
It thus infer the route with this object's name convention, which will be client_path like it would be user_path for current_user.

Does this route exists ?
If not and it is another one, you need to give simple_form the url for the form to be submited :

```
= simple_form_for current_client, url: loremipsum_path, remote: true do |f|
```

In Ruby on Rails, everything is based on conventions. Mostly naming conventions. That's how the ORM works, but also the routes, controller/views link, etc.
If you do not give options, the helpers/engine/librairies will infer based on naming they have on hand.